# Access Database Table setup

Tags: ms-access

I am setting up a program for contacts. I want to keep track of the contact and their email and phone number and what company they work for if we have that readily available. I will not always have the company they work for though so I set it up line this:

```
tblContacts
  ContactID
  ContactName
  ContactPhoneNumber
tblCompanies
  CompanyID
  CompanyName
tblContactsInCompanies
  CICID
  CompanyID
  ContactID
```

I did the ContactsInCompanies because not all of the contacts would have a company assigned. Now I am trying to get all of the contacts with the company name they are in if it is available and I cannot get the Joins to work.

Since I am having so much trouble, I thought I would ask if that is the way it should be set up or not (would anyone recommend a different setup). If that is OK, how would I get the list of all contacts and the company name if it is assigned? I have been trying to LEFT JOIN and INNER JOIN but I just get an error unless all are INNER JOIN but then it doesn't show contacts that do not have a company.

Comment: I have tried this but it errors out:
SELECT Contacts.*, Companies.CompanyName
FROM (Companies INNER JOIN ContactsInCompanies ON Companies.CompanyID = ContactsInCompanies.CompanyID) RIGHT JOIN Contacts ON Contacts.ContactID = ContactsInCompanies.ContactID;

I read that you cannot have an inner join inside an outer join so I tried it this way. Didn't work.

Comment: I think I got it. 

SELECT Contacts.*, Companies.CompanyName
FROM Companies RIGHT JOIN (Contacts LEFT JOIN ContactsInCompanies ON Contacts.ContactID = ContactsInCompanies.ContactID) ON Companies.CompanyID = ContactsInCompanies.CompanyID;


This seems to work. I was finally able to get a combination that worked. Thanks for looking.

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to get a combination that worked.

```
SELECT Contacts.*, Companies.CompanyName
FROM Companies RIGHT JOIN (Contacts LEFT JOIN ContactsInCompanies ON 
  Contacts.ContactID = ContactsInCompanies.ContactID) ON 
  Companies.CompanyID = ContactsInCompanies.CompanyID;
```

These always seem to confuse me. :( Thanks for looking.